# Presta Shop errors on registration

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

recently I made SEO optimization for client of mine, and I had to change some things on the server, like use PHP 7 and in Presta Shop admin panel to enable caching and SEO links.
I don`t use Presta Shop and I am not familiar with it, but some of this changes broke something in the code.
When new user tries to registrate it gets that error :

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Access to undeclared static property: Validate::$data in /home/unikalna/public_html/classes/ObjectModel.php:1032 Stack trace: #0 /home/unikalna/public_html/controllers/front/AuthController.php(406): ObjectModelCore->validateController() #1 /home/unikalna/public_html/controllers/front/AuthController.php(252): AuthControllerCore->processSubmitAccount() #2 /home/unikalna/public_html/classes/controller/Controller.php(171): AuthControllerCore->postProcess() #3 /home/unikalna/public_html/classes/Dispatcher.php(373): ControllerCore->run() #4 /home/unikalna/public_html/index.php(28): DispatcherCore->dispatch() #5 {main} thrown in /home/unikalna/public_html/classes/ObjectModel.php on line 1032
```

And also if its already registered and tries to buy something.

Version :PrestaShop™ 1.6.0.6

**Solved : Presta Shop 1.6 don`t work with PHP 7**

Comment: You are trying to access the $data property of Validate class statically.  Check is it declared as static in Validate class.

Comment: public static function isMySQLEngine($engine)
 {
  return (in_array($engine, array('InnoDB', 'MyISAM')));
 }

 public static function isUnixName($data)
 {
  return preg_match('/^[a-z0-9\._-]+$/ui', $data);
 }

 public static function isTablePrefix($data)
 {
  // Even if "-" is theorically allowed, it will be considered a syntax error if you do not add backquotes (`) around the table name
  return preg_match('/^[a-z0-9_]+$/ui', $data);
 }



I think that is what you ask me about @AlankarMore ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

/home/unikalna/public_html/classes/ObjectModel.php:1032

**OLD CODE**

```
if (!empty($value) || $value === '0' || ($field == 'postcode' && $value == '0')) {
    if (isset($data['validate']) && !Validate::$data['validate']($value) && (!empty($value) || $data['required'])) {
                $errors[$field] = '<b>'.self::displayFieldName($field, get_class($this), $htmlentities).'</b> '.Tools::displayError('is invalid.');
            } else {
                if (isset($data['copy_post']) && !$data['copy_post']) {
                    continue;
                }
                if ($field == 'passwd') {
                    if ($value = Tools::getValue($field)) {
                        $this->{$field} = Tools::encrypt($value);
                    }
                } else {
                    $this->{$field} = $value;
                }
            }
        }
```

**Replace with below code block**

***NEW CODE***

```
if (!empty($value) || $value === '0' || ($field == 'postcode' && $value == '0')) {
   if (isset($data['validate']) && !call_user_func('Validate::'.$data['validate'],$value) && (!empty($value) || $data['required'])) {
    $errors[$field] = '<b>'.self::displayFieldName($field, get_class($this), $htmlentities).'</b> '.Tools::displayError('is invalid.');
            } else {
                if (isset($data['copy_post']) && !$data['copy_post']) {
                    continue;
                }
                if ($field == 'passwd') {
                    if ($value = Tools::getValue($field)) {
                        $this->{$field} = Tools::encrypt($value);
                    }
                } else {
                    $this->{$field} = $value;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Just copied and pasted. Worked like a charm.

Comment: Thanks, replacing `!Validate::$data['validate']($value)` with `!call_user_func('Validate::'.$data['validate'],$value)` helped